# Fetching details of row of a jquery datatable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatables

Edit data function

[image]

When I click on edit button popup is coming but the row details are not getting fetched and send to modal popup.

This is code behind for action on edit button

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as image.

Comment: Please share code of edit button binding